# perl - push not appending to the end of the array

Tags: perl

```
  DB<2> n
  main::(/home/repsa/temper.pl:84):  my $tttdiskhumber=$myTemprecord[-1];
   DB<2> n
  main::(/home/repsa/temper.pl:87):  push(@myMainrecord,$tttdiskhumber);
   DB<2> p @myMainrecord
   t2agvio701vhost03t2adsap7011
   DB<3> p $tttdiskhumber
  hdisk6
   DB<4> n
   main::(/home/repsa/temper.pl:88): @myTemprecord=();
    DB<4> p @myMainrecord
    hdisk6o701vhost03t2adsap7011
   DB<5>
```

Why my last push is not appending to the end of the array? 
Any help is appreciated....

Comment: You should use `x` instead of `p` to print out data stuctures in the debugger.

Comment: Show your code, not a debugging session.

Comment: Actually, show your code AND the debugging session

Answer (score 7):

oh it is. The problem is that you're sending a carriage return to the screen. It's probably trailing the previous element in the array.

```
$ perl -e'print "abc", "def\r", "ghi", "\n";'
ghidef
```

You probably read a Windows text file on a non-Windows system without convert the line endings, either in advance (using `dos2unix`) or when you read the file (by using `s/\s+\z//;` instead of `chomp;`).

---

As jordanm suggested in a comment, the debugger's `x` command will show you what you have better than `p`.

```
$ perl -d

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.33
Editor support available.

Enter h or `h h' for help, or `man perldebug' for more help.

my @a = ("abc", "def\r", "ghi");
1;
^D
main::(-:1):    my @a = ("abc", "def\r", "ghi");
  DB<1> s
main::(-:2):    1;
  DB<1> p @a
ghidef
  DB<2> x @a
0  'abc'
1  "def\cM"
2  'ghi'
  DB<3> q
```

Comment: Please excuse for delay reply . That helped ..Was not aware of x option ... Thank you  for the info and the inputs....